# Arduino Leonoardo not recognized by computer

Tags: windows, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Leonardo. It worked very well the last time, but now my Computer (Win 10) doesn't recognize it anymore. (I used Win 10 before too). 
After pressing the "reset-button" it works for a few seconds, but after that it's gone again.

Do you have any ideas, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please add error which gives you Arduino IDE and port list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [arduino leonardo not recognized by usb cable in windows 8 pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121485/arduino-leonardo-not-recognized-by-usb-cable-in-windows-8-pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the Leonardo driver.
change the usb wire. 
if it is not worke then the boot loader got corrupted. 
check the link bellow 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP